# Content projection with *ngIf not work fine

Tags: angular

I have a strange behavior using ng-content with *ngIf inside a component, see this plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/BZim5lMhihuyAkDPfzZ6?p=preview

It a checkbox component that shows a label at the left or right of checkbox depends of `right` attribute.

```
@Component({
  selector: "em-checkbox",
  template: `
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="checkbox">
    <label *ngIf="right">
      <input type="checkbox"> 
      <ng-content></ng-content>
    </label>
    <label *ngIf="!right">
      <ng-content></ng-content>
      <input type="checkbox"> 
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
  `
})
export class EmCheckbox {
  @Input() right = false;
}
```

It only works with the first ng-content but not with the second, I cant put the label on the right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ng-content can only be used once (see https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/9173).

But I have the feeling you don't really need to use it twice by just adapting (and actually, simplifying) your template:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="checkbox">
    <label>
      <input *ngIf="right" type="checkbox"> 
      <ng-content></ng-content>
      <input *ngIf="!right" type="checkbox"> 
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what about this case: I have component 'layout' and if variable `userLoggedIn==true` I want to present `<section><ng-content></ng-content></section>` and if not, I want to present: `<article><ng-content></ng-content></article>` - how to do it ?

Comment: good question, I also have non-empty elements which I want to display conditionally each with the projected content inside but it seems like angular doesn't support this use case